# How to add Creation Date to already existing Records in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, jpa

I have a entity table in MySQL wherein I forgot to include `creation_date` of the record. That is, whenever a user saves his user information, a record gets created in User table in MySQL, but I forgot to include a column `creation_date` which I could easily set to current date while the user would hit save.

Now - there are currently more than 40 records in the system, with no creation date.  I want to track when each user was created.

Is there is a workaround to this?  If I now add the new column `creation_date`, does MySQL keep any timestamp which I can directly use & set it to this column?

My code is written in Java, JSF, making use of JPA, deployed on Glassfish.

Any help would be highly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: There is a system database, called `information_schema` in MySQL, you may want to track what's going on there, however I doubt that you will be able to "restore" missing time stamps

Comment: @Jens - Sharing code won't help. Its a design issue, which I missed out. In one of my earlier work,  I did create a field called 'creation_date' , which I used to set at the time of initializing an object or entity.

Comment: @HCRockWorks if you did not store the date, it is not available - you could get it from some app logs if you have any, or just assign now() for those old rows. Or guess.. Or check if you have binlogs enabled - it might be there.